# Using Wordpress with GIS?

Tags: web-mapping, software-recommendations, html, photos, wordpress

I am building a community-run map of neighbourhood stories that should feature photos, text, audio and video recordings.

Ideally, I hoped I could use a powerful and relatively user-friendly CMS like Wordpress to collect the stories, attach a geolocation to a post and display them on a Leaflet map, possibly generating layers by category and be able to filter by date etc... Then having content (html) displayed in a description div. However, my initial search for a plugin that would help me do this has not been successful as of yet. [Read here](https://merglindev.wordpress.com/2018/10/03/geotagging-wordpress-posts/).

My requirements for this project is to find an open-source solution and I need to be able to tag posts with Lat/Lon exactly and not an address since many points of interest are out in the bush.

I have created a quick prototype with Google My Maps, just to test how the data could be displayed (here with an audio embed from Soundcloud), but eventually, I don't want to use Google's API.
[image: Screenshot of Google Maps Description]

Comment: Just thinking aloud: You might be able to use Discourse as a blog and employ the [Locations plugin](https://meta.discourse.org/t/locations-plugin/69742). It already comes with a map or you can access the JSON feed.

Answer (score 1):

For Leaflet, it looks like this plugin may work for you and it should be free since you would probably only have one map: https://www.mapfig.com/leaflet-map-plugin/

If you are not opposed to using Mapbox, I heard of this company a few weeks ago and they offer a **Mapbox GL JS** plugin for Wordpress: https://www.mapster.me/wp-mapbox-gl-js/

Answer (score 1):

I have done this with CARTO (formerly CartoDB) and it was fantastic. Full control over data, appearance of icons, pop-ups, and most importantly basemaps. I would highly recommend checking out that platform.

Comment: Hi DPSSpatial. Thanks for your recommendation. Could you elaborate? Have you used Wordpress in combination with Carto or do you use Carto as the interface for people to add geotagged media?

Comment: Yes, we had a wordpress site with a big CARTO map embedded in the front 'masthead'... in terms of geotagged media, that is another question ... it could be a Google Form that gets linked to a CARTO map that could solve that question.

Answer (score 0):

Using [custom fields](https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields) you can add a latitude and a longitude to each of your posts. You can then retrieve a JSON of your posts' metadata* through the [Wordpress REST API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/) and create a marker for each lat-long pair on a [Leaflet](https://leafletjs.com/) map.

---

*To include the custom fields in the JSON response, an extra step is needed: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27566715/9778755